# Excel 2010 VBA function returning an array

Tags: excel, vba

I got a compile error for Excel 2010 VBA function implementation for a deposit computing. 
I want to return an array with interest rate and its value for the given deposit.

```
Function exe3djxInterestSelect(deposite)
  Dim V() As Variant
  ReDim V(1, 2)
  Select Case deposite
  Case Is < 0
    exe3djxInterestSelect = CVErr(xlErrNum)
  Case 0 To 1000
    V(1) = 0.055
    V(2) = deposite * 0.055
    exe3djxInterestSelect = V
  Case 1000 To 10000
    V(1) = 0.063
    V(2) = deposite * 0.063
    exe3djxInterestSelect = V
  Case 10000 To 100000
    V(1) = 0.073
    V(2) = deposite * 0.073
    exe3djxInterestSelect = V
  Case Else
    V(1) = 0.078
    V(2) = deposite * 0.078
    exe3djxInterestSelect = V
  End Select
```

End Function

It returns #VALUE! .

What is wrong with it ?

Thanks

Comment: It's easier to debug a UDF if you call it from a Sub instead of a worksheet.

Comment: I call it from a worksheet. I need to define a new function to call this one ? thanks !

Comment: Just create a sub in the same module: it only needs one line (eg)  `Dim v:v=exe3djxInterestSelect(100)`  Run it by pressing F5 with the cursor in the sub.

Comment: For debugging a worksheet formula without an extra sub, insert a breakpoint into your code with F9. After pressing Enter in a formula window, you'll be directed to the breakpoint in VBE window and you can use F8/Ctrl-F8 for stepping through the code.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up one-dimensional and two-dimensional arrays: try this

```
Function exe3djxInterestSelect(deposite)
  Dim V() As Variant
  ReDim V(1 To 1, 1 To 2)
  Select Case deposite
  Case Is < 0
    exe3djxInterestSelect = CVErr(xlErrNum)
  Case 0 To 1000
    V(1, 1) = 0.055
    V(1, 2) = deposite * 0.055
    exe3djxInterestSelect = V
  Case 1000 To 10000
    V(1, 1) = 0.063
    V(1, 2) = deposite * 0.063
    exe3djxInterestSelect = V
  Case 10000 To 100000
    V(1, 1) = 0.073
    V(1, 2) = deposite * 0.073
    exe3djxInterestSelect = V
  Case Else
    V(1, 1) = 0.078
    V(1, 2) = deposite * 0.078
    exe3djxInterestSelect = V
  End Select
End Function
```